# Estoy tratando de detectar el cambio de url con js pero no lo detecta

Tags: javascript, web, local-storage, storage

Trabajo en laravel y mi ruta con la que trabajo en javascript es : http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/create

Lo que quiero es que me detecte cuando cambie de  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/create a  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/ver y en ese momento me elimine el localstorage por ejemplo

Comment: ¿Cómo se modifica la URL y cómo tratas de detectar los cambios? Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

No queda muy claro si solo quieres que se borre el storage específicamente al cambio desde la url **ventas/create** a **ventas/ver**.

De ser así la estrategia que usaría sería almacenar la url actual, grabarla en el storage como previousURL y luego al cambiar de página compararla con la actual y si se da el match ahí gatillar la limpieza del storage.

Entonces quedaría algo como:

```javascript
if (localStorage.getItem("previousUrl") === null) {// Si no tenemos guardada ninguna URL grabamos la actual
    window.localStorage.setItem("previousUrl", document.URL);
} else {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("previousUrl") == 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/create' && document.URL=='http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/ver') {// Si viene de create y la pagina actual es ver
        window.localStorage.clear();// Borramos todo
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("previousUrl", document.URL);// Volvemos a grabar nuestra url
}
```

No está demas decir que el código debe ir al menos en las páginas **ventas/create** y **ventas/ver**

Este código no ha sido testeado :( pero espero que te sirva de guía.

Puedes [ver este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334435/is-it-possible-to-store-previous-url-in-back-button-which-will-work-directly) para tener una idea.

Answer (score -1):

podrías usar algo como:

```
if(window.location.href === 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/ver'){
  localStorage.clear()
}
```

Comment: Hola Maxi Ignacio, aunque tu respuesta puede ayudar como guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una explicación de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles y una descripción de lo que hace cada opción. Lee [answer] para más información.